# How do you change the look-and-feel of MapView display on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

This may not be possible, but I would like to change how maps look in the Android app I'm working on. I've gotten the basic functionality working via the MapView class, but I can't find any information on how I might change how the maps are rendered. For instance, I might want the background to be black instead of the normal tan. Any ideas?! Hack answers are fine at this point if there aren't any standard ways to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could try putting a transparent overlay item with a tinge.
- The MapView has a couple of modes like Satellite terrain
- Try using [OpenStreetMap](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Map_Features) for Android for a different look

Comment: Thanks! I've been looking into OSM as well. I thought about the transparent overlay, but aside from physically reading the pixel color values (which I don't know how to do) and replacing them with out values (which seems incredibly inefficient), I'm not sure how to do it that way. Thanks for the advice!